# SELECT UPDATE SQL Not Working

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sql-update

I have 2 forms

First Form has

```
Public Class frmMain

Friend strBillIDNumber As String
Friend strBillPassword As String
Friend ds As New DataSet
Friend cnn As OleDbConnection
Friend sql As String
Friend adptr As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim attempt As Integer = 1

Private Sub btnSign_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSign.Click

    Dim connectionString As String
    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Renz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\FINAL\Database\UsersDB.accdb;"
    sql = "Select ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, LOGINSTATUS from TblUser"
    cnn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        adptr = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
        adptr.Fill(ds)



        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0) = txtID.Text Then
                MessageBox.Show("UserName Matched")
                If ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1) = txtPassword.Text Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Password Matched")

                    If txtPassword.Text = "admin" Then
                        MessageBox.Show("You are now Logged In as Admin.")
                        frmFaculty.Show()
                        Me.Hide()
                    Else
                        frmStudent.lblSI.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0)
                        frmStudent.lblLN.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)
                        frmStudent.lblFN.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)
                        frmStudent.lblLS.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3)
                        MessageBox.Show("You are now Logged In.")
                        frmStudent.Show()
                        Me.Hide()
                    End If
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password.")
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Try Again." & vbNewLine & "ATTEMPT: " & attempt & " out of 3")
                    attempt = attempt + 1
                End If
            End If

        Next

        adptr.Dispose()
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please Try Again!")
    End Try

    'log-in attempt 3x fail'
    If attempt > 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have exceeded the number of login attempt." & vbNewLine & "Please Contact the Administrator.")
    End If
End Sub
```

And my Second Form Has

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmStudent
Dim TimeInHold As String
Private Sub loginBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loginBTN.Click

    Dim cnn2 As New OleDbConnection
    Dim Command As OleDbCommand
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sql2 As String
    Dim status As String

    Try
        cnn2 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Renz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\FINAL\Database\AuditDB.mdb;")
        cnn2.Open()

        sql2 = "INSERT INTO Audit ([ID],[TIMEIN]) VALUES('" & frmMain.txtID.Text & "','" & DateTime.Now & "')"

        Command = New OleDbCommand(sql2, cnn2)
        i = Command.ExecuteNonQuery

    Catch ex As Exception
        cnn2.Close()

    End Try

    MessageBox.Show("You have successfully Signed in." & vbNewLine & " Please Don't Forget to Logout.")
    frmMain.cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Renz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\FINAL\Database\UsersDB.accdb;")
    frmMain.cnn.Open()
    frmMain.adptr = New OleDbDataAdapter(frmMain.sql, frmMain.cnn)
    frmMain.adptr.Fill(frmMain.ds)
    If frmMain.ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0) = lblSI.Text Then
        frmMain.sql = "UPDATE TblUser SET LOGINSTATUS = 'SignedIn'"

        frmMain.cnn.Close()
    End If
    Me.Close()
    frmMain.Show()
    frmMain.txtID.Text = String.Empty
    frmMain.txtPassword.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

I can't get my SELECT and UPDATE sql statement to work that will get the data set from form 1.  And when the button is clicked, it will update the field "LoginStatus" to a value of "Signed In".

P.S. I'm creating a time-in, time-out monitoring system that will determine if the user is an admin or a student and will redirect them to their corresponding forms.  Student form will have sign in and sign out buttons, and will record their time in and time out.  When sign in is clicked, it will be grayed out.

Please Help..

Comment: Why is this in caps.   Please reformat so this is readable

Comment: I made an edit, pending review.

Comment: You need to learn about the [`WHERE` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) - when you're trying to find a matching row in a table, the right way to do that is to ask SQL to find the row. The wrong way to do it is to write `For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1`. You'll also need (soon) to find out about parameters, but once you've got the hang of the `WHERE` clause, at least your `UPDATE` won't change *every* row in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing executeNonQuery in second form and is there only one user then query is fine if more than one consider using " Where Clause" eg.

```
sql= "UPDATE TblUser SET LOGINSTATUS = 'SignedIn' where ID =" <provide id>
```

if that doesn't solve your problem then feel free to ask more.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
If frmMain.ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0) = lblSI.Text Then
    frmMain.sql = "UPDATE TblUser SET LOGINSTATUS = 'SignedIn'"

    frmMain.cnn.Close()
End If
```

It seems that the UPDATE statement doesn't get executed. 
I don't see ExecuteNonQuery for it.

**ps:** The UPDATE statement is to update all records in the table. Look out!
ps2: I'm not familiar with the VB(.net) :)

Comment: thanks for all the reply and sorry for the CAPS

    SO this statement will I use?
    SELECT LOGINTYPE FROM TblUser WHERE = ID = "' & frmMain.txtID.text & '"

Comment: and what will be the IF statement look like if I use the WHERE CLAUSE on my login button